# How to have ajaxstatus only for particular primefaces livescroll datatable in a jsf page?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

Hi guys I have two live scroll datatable in a same page once I scroll ajaxstatus is loading fine. But I want to implement ajax loading for the particular datatable live scroll process. For other events in the page ajaxloader should not load what to do ? I have included ajaxstatus in each datatable header. [check the image for more clarity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WA9BM.jpg)

```
<f:facet name="header">

    <p:ajaxStatus style="float:right;margin-right: 3em;padding-top: 0.2em;">

        <f:facet name="default">
            <p:graphicImage value="/resources/images/login/loading.gif" />
        </f:facet>

        <f:facet name="start">
            <p:graphicImage value="/resources/images/login/loading.gif" />
        </f:facet>

        <f:facet name="complete">

        </f:facet>

    </p:ajaxStatus>

</f:facet>
```

Comment: The ajaxStatus is overkill in this case imo. Just add a `p:graphicImage` and change the style (display attribute) on the onstart (show it) and  oncomplete (hide it) event of the livescroll ajax event (which is the page event iirc)

Comment: There is no livescroll ajax event in primefaces that's why  I tried using ajaxstatus.

Comment: I'm 100% sure I added a suggestion about that in my previous comment